# Google map marker is not showing in exact location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project, I have integrated google map. I am having one problem : when I search for a particular location, the marker is not displaying at the current point, it is showing somewhere else. However, latitude and longitude are correct, could you help me to understand what I am missing ?

Note: **For some locations, the marker is displayed on the correct location.**

Html code :

```
<input ng-model="address" class="form-control" ng-map-autocomplete/>
<ng-map zoom="18" center="{{address}}" style="width:650px; height:450px">
    <marker position="{{address}}" title="{{address}}"  draggable="true"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch(function ($scope) { return $scope.chosenPlaceDetails }, function () {
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.chosenPlaceDetails )) {
        $scope.latitude= $scope.chosenPlaceDetails.geometry.location.lat();
        $scope.longitude=$scope.chosenPlaceDetails.geometry.location.lng();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ng-map-autocomplete doc, {{address}} is only the value used for the autocomplete. You can attach a "detail" value which will contain the lat and long of your location.

```
    <input type="text"  ng-map-autocomplete ng-model="autocomplete" options="options" details="details"/>
```

Then, in your ng-map directive, you can access the lat and long

```
<ng-map zoom="18" center="{{details.geometry.location.lat}},{{details.geometry.location.lng}}" style="width:650px; height:450px">
    <marker position="{{details.geometry.location.lat}},{{details.geometry.location.lng}}" title="{{address}}"  draggable="true"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

If you want to update in your controller, you can put a $watcher on details

```
$scope.$watch('details', function (newValue, oldValue) {
if (oldValue == undefined){
  $scope.latitude = 0 /*default value */
  $scope.longitude= 0 /*default value */
}
 $scope.latitude= newValue.geometry.location.lat;
$scope.longitude=newValue.geometry.location.lng;
});
```

then you can access the position in the ng-map directive with your new variables.

```
<ng-map zoom="18" center="{{latitude}},{{longitude}}" style="width:650px; height:450px">
    <marker position="{{latitude}},{{longitude}}" title="{{address}}"  draggable="true"></marker>
</ng-map>
```

Hope it helps.
Source: https://github.com/iazi/ngMapAutocomplete

Ps: Code not tested, I merely try to recreate what I did month ago

Comment: If you want to update also in the controller, maybe put a $watcher on the Details variable

`$scope.$watch('details', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.latitude= newValue.geometry.location.lat;
    $scope.longitude=newValue.geometry.location.lng
    }
}); `

Comment: Hi Roux in my controller i have given initial values like this: $scope.address = "12180 Park Ave S, Tacoma, WA 98447, USA";
 $scope.lat="47.146427232895235";
 $scope.lng="-122.4420750597717";

Comment: Can u please edit your answer with controller clearly

Comment: Hi Roux how to pass initial values i.e old values, For entered values i am getting marker correctly. but for initial page load how to give latitude longitude i.e old values

Comment: Well, in the watcher, if OldValue is empty, you can define a default value. I'll edit

Comment: Thanks Roux it helped me lot